# Not able to install vim

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, libpng

Iam trying to install vim and i get the following error

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpng12-0 : Breaks: libpng12-0:i386 (!= 1.2.50-2+deb8u3) but 1.2.54-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libpng12-0:i386 : Breaks: libpng12-0 (!= 1.2.54-1ubuntu1) but 1.2.50-2+deb8u3 is to be installed
 vim : Depends: vim-common (= 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2) but 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
       Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I tried to run apt-get -f install with no packages.Then i got this error

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
libpng12-0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpng12-0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 594 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 116 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpng12-0 amd64 1.2.54-1ubuntu1 [116 kB]
Fetched 116 kB in 1s (69.8 kB/s)     
(Reading database ... 240235 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1) over (1.2.50-2+deb8u3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libpng12-0/ANNOUNCE', which is different from other instances of package libpng12-0:amd64
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If anyone could suggest the reason of this error that would  be very helpful

Comment: Perhaps askubuntu.com would be a better forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).